# How to work with highly skewed data -pandas dataframe

Tags: python

The dataset consist of 4000+ records. Here , trying to identify anomaly in 'duration' attribute. However, when the box plot is drown, can find that it is highly skewed. Tried to transform data, however results are not got. Attaching the boxplot below. How should we proceed in these cases.

[Boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBGpa.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a histogram of your plot and try to fit a distribution on your data. Suppose you were able to fit a standard normal distribution on your data, then you could read off anomalies in your data by checking the probability of the sample in your distribution. If this probability is smaller than a threshold probability p, then you could mark it as an anomoly.